# How to Oracle SQL return where values when now records found.?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customers table[image]

What I want is when I run the query some thing like below

```
SELECT (<what should be the query here?>)
WHERE CustomerID  in (2,3,13,18);
```

it should return the values used in where the condition for which it didn't find any records, something like below

```
Customer ID   CustomerName   ContactName Address
13           null            null        null
18            null            null        null
```

Comment: You will need to create a temporary table and then perform a LEFT JOIN on it and the Customer table. This will mean that you'll get each ID record back, and NULL values where the record wasn't found.

Comment: @Harishfysx, You said below in comments that `I don't want to hard code them all?`, but you do have to mention the values for the `in` clause. right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` -- but you need a table with the values.  Here is one way to construct that table:

```
select *
from (select 2 as customerid from dual union all
      select 3 as customerid from dual union all
      select 13 as customerid from dual union all
      select 18 as customerid from dual
     ) c left join
     customers c
     using (customerid)
where c.customerid is null;
```

Comment: what if there are hundreds of where values? I dont want to hard code them all?

Comment: Are you writing the SQL directly, or do you have software that generates executes this SQL on your behalf? E.g. Entity Framework or JHibernate or something.

Comment: @Harishfysx . . . You can construct the query using a spreadsheet or similar tool.

Comment: @ Gorodon Linoff - unfortunately data is in the database. And it has thousands of records

Comment: @Harishfysx . . . Then the derived table should be a query that returns the values you care about.  That is simpler anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table collection expression and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it to your table:

```sql
SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE AS customer_id,
       c.CustomerName,
       c.ContactName,
       c.Address
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 2, 3, 13, 18 ) ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers c
       ON ( t.COLUMN_VALUE = c.Customer_ID )
WHERE  c.Customer_ID IS NULL;
```

So, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customers ( customer_id, customername, contactname, address ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,
       'Customer' || LEVEL,
       'Contact' || LEVEL,
       'Address' || LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMERNAME | CONTACTNAME | ADDRESS
> ----------: | :----------- | :---------- | :------
>          13 | null         | null        | null   
>          18 | null         | null        | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5dc8ffafb3da3f878911f7524320b154)*